# How to unlock pdf buffer array in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-lib.js

I have tried using pdf-lib but could not find any unlock functionality with the library. I also tried with qpdf command using spawn child process but even it was not helpful. Can anyone please help me on this one ?

```
const qpdfProcess = spawn('qpdf', ['--password=401000056762', '--decrypt', '-', '-']);
qpdfProcess.stdin.write(pdfBuffer)
const decryptedPdf = qpdfProcess.stdout()
```